# Which protocol has the better perfomance TAP or NTor

Tags: circuit, protocol

Just wondering, which protocol, TAP or NTor is less computationally intensive for a relay to process and why ?

Thanks Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ntor offers reduced [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) for circuit setup compared to TAP. Tor circuits are setup [one hop at a time](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n682) with each link using [TLS](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n766). Diffie-Hellman (DH) is the algorithm used for computing keys to be exchanged and is responsible for what we conceptually know as [forward-secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

**Notable differences between TAP and ntor**

[Tor Authentication Protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n821) (TAP), the original/legacy handshake, will be used where ntor isn't supported.

- Generating a DH key is computationally expensive
- Need to generate DH public/private values, and perform exchange at each node, as the circuit is extended
- DH Keys are [encrypted/decrypted with RSA at each node](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n436) using onion-key
- An analysis of TAP can be found [here](http://www.freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/tap:pet2006.pdf)

[ntor](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n868) is the handshake added in 0.2.4.8-alpha. It will be used where consensus method is [at least 16](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2177) and an [ntor public key](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n448) is available.

- eliminates the use of RSA encryption-decryption from circuit setup
- uses [Curve25519 to reduce DH computational complexity](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) while also [preserving forward-secrecy](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/ntor.pdf) and offering timing-attack resistance
- enables *precomputation* of values during idle cycles before they're needed
- uses *predistributed* values ([identity, ntor-onion](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n895)) in computations
- reduces [communication and computational complexity](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/216-ntor-handshake.txt#n131) during circuit setup

-- leeroy